# Can one use a view as a source on pt-table-sync?

Tags: mysql, percona-tools

Any attempt to fill a table from a view results in an error, as the source-table does not exist:

```
Error getting table structure for TABLE_NAME on SOURCE_DSN_DATA doesnt handle CREATE TABLE without quoting.
at /usr/local/bin/pt-table-sync line 2872. Ensure that the table exists and is accessible.  
while doing TABLE_NAME on DESTINATION_NAME
```

I know that the source table doesn't exist, as I am trying to use a view as a source instead. Access is not a problem either. As tests with a source-table instead of a source-view confirmed.

In the DSN, I use `d=` and `t=` to define the database and table/view.

Replacing the view with a table and running the `pt-table-sync` again works as expected, so there seem to be no issue in the command/parameters themselves.

```
pt-table-sync --execute DSN_SOURCE DSN_TARGET --verbose --print
```

The [documentation by percona](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-table-sync.html) does not indicate any additional parameters for what I want to do.

Is there any way to use a view as a source on pt-table-sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:  No.

Long answer:

Why do you need to sync a view?

- If the `VIEW` has a single table 'under the covers', "syncing" the table has the effect of syncing the View.
- If the `VIEW` has multiple tables, then simply sync each table.